# TF 2.0 MLP accuracy always zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, mlp

I've written a minimal example of a simple neural network  that fits a given function (a multilayer perceptron for regression).

During the training process the loss decresses as expected and the model works fine. However, the accuracy remains constant and equal to 0.0 at all times, and I don't understand why. What am I missing here?

I guess there is some technical detail that prevents the accuracy from updating?

The training process and the resulting model can be seen [in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1agP.png)

Thank you very much for any help you can provide! ;)

PS- Here is a minimal example to reproduce this result:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

# Create TRAINING data
noise = 0.1
N=500
Xt = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, size=(N,))
Yt = np.sin(Xt) + noise * np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=Xt.shape)
# Create VALIDATION data
Nv = int(0.1*N)
Xv = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, size=(Nv,))
Yv = np.sin(Xv) + noise * np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=Xv.shape)

# Create model
model = Sequential()
model.add( Dense(10, activation='tanh',input_shape=(1,)) )
model.add( Dense(5, activation='tanh') )
model.add( Dense(1, activation=None) )

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit & evaluate
history = model.fit(Xt, Yt, validation_data=(Xv,Yv),
                            epochs=100,
                             verbose=2)

results = model.evaluate(Xv, Yv,verbose=0)
print('\n\nEvaluating model, loss/acc:', results)


## PLOTS
fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])              # losses
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1,0], sharex=ax1)  # accuracies
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[:,1])              # data & model

# Plot learning curve
err = history.history['loss']
val_err = history.history['val_loss']
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
ax1.plot(err,label='loss')
ax1.plot(val_err,label='val_loss')
ax2.plot(acc,label='accuracy')
ax2.plot(val_acc,label='val_accuracy')
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax2.set_ylim(bottom=-0.01)
ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()

# Plot test
# Generate "continous" data for pretty test
x = np.linspace(np.min(Xt),np.max(Xt),1000)
y = model.predict(x)

ax3.scatter(Xt, Yt, label='Training')
ax3.scatter(Xv, Yv, c='C2', label='Validation')
ax3.plot(x, y, 'C3-', lw=4, label='Model')
ax3.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: 'accuracy' is only meaningful for a classification task where targets are binary. Your targets are continuous, and your model never gets the target value _exactly_ right, so it has 0 accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

As Swier pointed out in the comment accuracy is meant for classification.
Nevertheless I thought that some points should yield the exact target value, that's why I was expecting acc>0.
Anyway I mapped the problem to a integer-only problem and in that scenario the accuracy is different from zero. Obviously not a useful metric, but at least it makes (mathematical) sense.
Thanks!!